# wubildr.mbr missing or corrupt

Tags: wubi, dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wubildr.mbr missing or corrupt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25764/wubildr-mbr-missing-or-corrupt)

I'm dual booting W7 and Ubuntu (installed from Wubi). I've had it up and running a few times but today I'm getting a message from Windows Boot Manager when I select Ubuntu that wubildr.mbr is missing or corrupt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.