# wubildr.mbr missing or corrupt

Tags: windows-7, wubi

I'm dual booting W7 and Ubuntu (installed from Wubi). I've had it up and running a few times but today I'm getting a message from Windows Boot Manager when I select Ubuntu that wubildr.mbr is missing or corrupt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @creade So you're using windows boot loader to load linux? as opposed to using grub(2) to load windows?

Comment: Is Ubuntu on the same drive as Windows, or external? Are you using anything special on your disk, such as encryption or RAID?

Comment: @xenoterracide wubi - is a weird way to install ubuntu - inside big file on windows partition so there's no other options, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

It is a general problem that happens with WUBI.Since Ubuntu is installed to a file inside windows partition,it becomes susceptible to corruptions that generally happen in Windows.You can reinstall Ubuntu but I recommend a full install.

Comment: I did a fresh install and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this but first use `bcdedit` from an elevated command prompt to find your Ubuntu partition and its identifier. Then try:

```
bcdedit /set {<ubuntu_id>} device partition=<ubuntu_part>:
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but the partition was already set correctly in bcdedit.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot%20boot%20into%20Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that error in one of my Wubi installations on Windows 7. Near as I can tell, it was just a hardware quirk, since I don't see that error anymore now that I've installed on a different (desktop instead of a laptop) machine.

And even when the error popped up, everything still worked fine. It just took a couple minutes to work past the error message and then the boot process continued as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In `C:\ubuntu\winboot` you will find a copy of `wubildr` and `wubildr.mbr`.

Copy them to `C:\` and restart the system.

Comment: be careful if the ubuntu folder is on another partition

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I had installed:

- Windows xp
- Windows 8
- Ubuntu

When it comes to the BOOT panel, I choosed Ubuntu directly and got this message. 
BUT!! When I whent to "Windows xp" to could try the suggested option by: "enzotib" about moving it to another Directory inside Windows.

Following happened:

- On the BOOT panel i choosed "Windows xp"
- A "NEW" different format BOOT windows apear with just 2 options:
- Windows xp? o Ubuntu? (Windows 8 did not apear on this new BOOT panel)
- I choosed Ubuntu and installed fast and simple!

Hopes helps someone in the future to "Don't freak out"!
Best regards,
from Barcelona