# Wubildr.mbr missing or corrupt 0xc0000098

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wubildr.mbr missing or corrupt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25764/wubildr-mbr-missing-or-corrupt)

I know there are like a million question like this, but i tried everything they say and I still have that problem.
I downloaded Wubi, and executed it. Before that, I did a partition (:E) only for Ubuntu, and told Wubi to install Ubuntu there. When it finishes, i reboot, and when i choose Ubuntu (between Ubuntu or Windows 7), this is what appears:

The file must be missing or corrupt:

\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

0xc0000098