# Wubi not working on 64-bit Intel i5 2nd generation

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit

I have faced a problem of installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my 64-bit Intel Core i5 laptop and gave me this message after rebooting the device and I didn't know what to do.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

  Status: 0xc000000e  

  Info: Application could not load. Corrupt or missing.
```

Can you help me please solve this problem to install it via Wubi?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a [somewhat common error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25764/wubildr-mbr-missing-or-corrupt?lq=1) with Wubi. One of the answers in the linked question just recommends doing a reinstall or a full dual-boot installation of Ubuntu. If you can't access Windows either, then you may have to run a repair disc (boot-repair-disk, Windows repair disc, etc) to restore the MBR to factory default.